# How to derive this relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, geodesics

According to *A relativist's toolkit* by Poisson, the expansion of null radial geodetic in the Schwarzschild spacetime is $$\theta=\dfrac{2}{r}$$
How to derive this expression?

The expansion is defined as $$\theta=k^\alpha_{\phantom{\alpha};\alpha} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-g}} \left( \sqrt{-g}k^\alpha \right)_{,\alpha}$$

and $k_\alpha=-\partial_\alpha \left[t-\int dr \left(1-\dfrac{2m}{r}\right)^{-1}\right]$

If I substitute all the values of the Schwarzschild metric, I get:

$$\theta = -\dfrac{2m}{(r-2m)^2}\neq\dfrac{2}{r}$$

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: could you please add page/equation reference?

Comment: @magma the page is 52, but the equation is in the text, there is no number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably made some trivial error. For example, did you forget to raise the index on $k$?

$$k_\alpha=\left(-1,\frac{1}{1-2m/r},0,0\right)\tag1$$

$$k^\alpha=\left(\frac{1}{1-2m/r},1,0,0\right)\tag2$$

$$\sqrt{-g}=r^2\sin\theta\tag3$$

In the calculation of $\Theta$, only the $\alpha=r$ term contributes:

$$\Theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\left( \sqrt{-g}\,k^\alpha \right)_{,\alpha}=\frac{1}{r^2\sin\theta}\left(r^2\sin\theta\right)_{,r}=\frac2r\tag4.$$

Comment: @mattiav27 I had a mistake in the determinant, but I’ve fixed it.